# How can I add a filter for operating system in MIcrosoft Graph API Powershell script

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I used the link below to create a PowerShell script to use in Microsoft Graph API and it works fine but I need to filter the results to only specific operating system values like "Android" or "Apple".

https://www.smthwentright.com/2022/08/10/creating-azure-ad-groups-based-on-intune-device-properties-using-azure-automation-and-ms-graph/#comments

Full credit to this site for this script and instructions.

```
 
##############################
## Parameters
##############################
 
 
##############################
## Variables
##############################
 
$TenantID       = Get-AutomationVariable -Name TenantID
$ApplicationID  = Get-AutomationVariable -Name IntuneGroupsApplicationID
$AppSecret      = Get-AutomationVariable -Name IntuneGroupsAppSecret
 
$AADGroupID     = Get-AutomationVariable -Name PrimaryUsersID
 
##############################
## Functions
##############################
 
Function Get-MSGraphAuthToken {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param(
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [pscredential]$Credential,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$tenantID
    )
    
    #Get token
    $AuthUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantID/oauth2/token"
    $Resource = 'graph.microsoft.com'
    $AuthBody = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=$($credential.UserName)&client_secret=$($credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password)&resource=https%3A%2F%2F$Resource%2F"
 
    $Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $AuthUri -Body $AuthBody
    If ($Response.access_token) {
        return $Response.access_token
    }
    Else {
        Throw "Authentication failed"
    }
}
Function Invoke-MSGraphQuery {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParametersetname = "Default")]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Default')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Refresh')]
        [string]$URI,
 
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'Default')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'Refresh')]
        [string]$Body,
 
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Default')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Refresh')]
        [string]$token,
 
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'Default')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'Refresh')]
        [ValidateSet('GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE')]
        [string]$method = "GET",
    
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'Default')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'Refresh')]
        [switch]$recursive,
    
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Refresh')]
        [switch]$tokenrefresh,
    
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Refresh')]
        [pscredential]$credential,
    
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Refresh')]
        [string]$tenantID
    )
    $authHeader = @{
        'Accept'        = 'application/json'
        'Content-Type'  = 'application/json'
        'Authorization' = "Bearer $Token"
    }
    
    [array]$returnvalue = $()
    Try {
        If ($body) {
            $Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URI -Headers $authHeader -Body $Body -Method $method -ErrorAction Stop
        }
        Else {
            $Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URI -Headers $authHeader -Method $method -ErrorAction Stop
        }
    }
    Catch {
        If (($Error[0].ErrorDetails.Message | ConvertFrom-Json -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).error.Message -eq 'Access token has expired.' -and $tokenrefresh) {
            $token = Get-MSGraphAuthToken -credential $credential -tenantID $TenantID
 
            $authHeader = @{
                'Content-Type'  = 'application/json'
                'Authorization' = $Token
            }
            $returnvalue = $()
            If ($body) {
                $Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URI -Headers $authHeader -Body $Body -Method $method -ErrorAction Stop
            }
            Else {
                $Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $authHeader -Method $method
            }
        }
        Else {
            Throw $_
        }
    }
 
    $returnvalue += $Response
    If (-not $recursive -and $Response.'@odata.nextLink') {
        Write-Warning "Query contains more data, use recursive to get all!"
        Start-Sleep 1
    }
    ElseIf ($recursive -and $Response.'@odata.nextLink') {
        If ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'default') {
            If ($body) {
                $returnvalue += Invoke-MSGraphQuery -URI $Response.'@odata.nextLink' -token $token -body $body -method $method -recursive -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            }
            Else {
                $returnvalue += Invoke-MSGraphQuery -URI $Response.'@odata.nextLink' -token $token -method $method -recursive -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            }
        }
        Else {
            If ($body) {
                $returnvalue += Invoke-MSGraphQuery -URI $Response.'@odata.nextLink' -token $token -body $body -method $method -recursive -tokenrefresh -credential $credential -tenantID $TenantID -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            }
            Else {
                $returnvalue += Invoke-MSGraphQuery -URI $Response.'@odata.nextLink' -token $token -method $method -recursive -tokenrefresh -credential $credential -tenantID $TenantID -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            }
        }
    }
    Return $returnvalue
}
 
##############################
## Scriptstart
##############################
 
#Authenticate to Enterprise Application
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($ApplicationID, (ConvertTo-SecureString $AppSecret -AsPlainText -Force))
$Token = Get-MSGraphAuthToken -credential $Credential -TenantID $TenantID
 
#Get all managed devices
$ResourceURL = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceManagement/managedDevices"
$managedDevices = Invoke-MSGraphQuery -method GET -URI $resourceURL -token $token -recursive
$managedDevices = $managedDevices.Value
 
#Get all members in our current AAD groups to later be used to compare
$ResourceURL = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/$AADGroupID/members"
$GroupMembers = Invoke-MSGraphQuery -method GET -URI $resourceURL -token $token -recursive
$GroupMembers = $GroupMembers.Value
 
Write-Output "$($GroupMembers.count) members in AAD Group"
 
#Removing duplicates and Empty objects
$SortedObjects = @()
ForEach ($Device in $managedDevices) {
    #Remove if Device has no Primary User
    If ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Device.userID)) { Write-Output "Skipping due to Empty InputObject" ; Continue }
    #Remove if user is already in collection
    If ($SortedObjects -contains $Device.userID) { Write-Output "Skipping due to InputObject already exists in collection" ; Continue }
    $SortedObjects += $Device.userId
}
 
If ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($GroupMembers.ID)) { $Temp = New-Object System.Object ; $Temp | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ID" -Value "Temp"; $GroupMembers += $Temp }
#Compare the current group members againt our attirubte list
$Compare = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $GroupMembers.ID -DifferenceObject $SortedObjects
 
#Add the users to the group
ForEach ($User in $Compare) {
    $UserID = $User.InputObject
    
    #If User is no longer amongst primary intune users but in the group it needs to be removed
    If ($User.SideIndicator -eq "<=") {
 
        Write-Output "Removing User with ID $UserID"
        Try {
            $ResourceURL = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/$AADGroupID/members/$UserID/`$ref"
            $RemoveUser = Invoke-MSGraphQuery -method DELETE -URI $resourceURL -token $token -Body $body
        }
        Catch {
            Write-Output "Error occured with removing user ID: $UserID"
        }  
    }
    #If the user is not in the group but is a primary intune user it needs to be added
    If ($User.SideIndicator -eq "=>") {
 
        Write-Output "Adding User with ID $($UserID)"
 
        $Body = @{
            "@odata.id"="https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/$UserID"
        } | ConvertTo-Json
        Try {
            $ResourceURL = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/$AADGroupID/members/`$ref"
            $AddUser = Invoke-MSGraphQuery -method POST -URI $resourceURL -token $token -Body $body
        }
        Catch {
            Write-Output "Error occured with adding user ID: $UserID"
        }
 
    }
}
```

I tried the following filter but not getting results and I added it to the "$ResourceURL" section of the script, should I be putting it in a different place?

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/managedDevices?$filter=operatingSystem eq 'Android' or operatingSystem eq 'iOS'
```